# Updating column B value case when conditional statement is true

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update Column C value to 1.5 when Column A = Column B Else it should be 4 in SQL Server.

I wrote something like this

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Column C = 1.5 CASE WHEN Column A = Column B ELSE 4 END NewColumn.
```

I have never used UPDATE and CASE WHEN statement.

Comment: So why not use a computed column and never EVER have to update the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
UPDATE MyTable
    SET C = (CASE WHEN A = B THEN 1.5 ELSE 4 END)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **[`IIF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** as

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET C = IIF(A=B, 1.5, 4);
```